# How can I determine the type of an HTML element in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, dom

I need a way to determine the type of an HTML element in JavaScript. It has the ID, but the element itself could be a `<div>`, a `<form>` field, a `<fieldset>`, etc. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 478, accepted):

[`nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName) is the attribute you are looking for. For example:

```
var elt = document.getElementById('foo');
console.log(elt.nodeName);
```

Note that `nodeName` returns the element name capitalized and without the angle brackets, which means that if you want to check if an element is an `<div>` element you could do it as follows:

```
elt.nodeName == "DIV"
```

While this would not give you the expected results:

```
elt.nodeName == "<div>"
```

Comment: I recommend doing it like this:

if(elt.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "div") { ... }

This way, if for some reason it is no longer returned in uppercase letters (lowercase or mixed), you won't have to change it and this code will still work fine.

Comment: In response to @TheCuBeMan, using toLowerCase() means you also need to make sure nodeName exists (if it's at all possible elt is not, in fact, an element): `if (elt.nodeName && elt.nodeName.toLowerCase() === 'div') { ... }`

Comment: what about `localName`?

Answer (score 70):

What about [`element.tagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Core-20001113/core.html#ID-104682815)?

See also [`tagName` docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName).

Comment: According to timestamps you beat me by less than 1 second!

Comment: From QuirksMode: My advice is not to use tagName at all.
nodeName contains all functionalities of tagName, plus a few more. Therefore nodeName is always the better choice.

Comment: @bdukes Are you still here? You say you quote QuirksMode, but I can't find the original text there, and I'm curious what the differences are. As well as `localName`.

Comment: https://www.quirksmode.org/dom/core/#t23 looks like `nodeName` also provides the name of attribute, text, and comment nodes, in addition to tags/elements. I believe `localName` is from the XML APIs. If you know you're always dealing with an element there's probably not a lot of difference, but `nodeName` is the more versatile option.

Answer (score 46):

You can use generic code inspection via [`instanceof`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof):

```
var e = document.getElementById('#my-element');
if (e instanceof HTMLInputElement) {}         // <input>
elseif (e instanceof HTMLSelectElement) {}    // <select>
elseif (e instanceof HTMLTextAreaElement) {}  // <textarea>
elseif (  ... ) {}                            // any interface
```

Look [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) for a complete list of interfaces.

Answer (score 23):

Sometimes you want `element.constructor.name`

```
document.createElement('div').constructor.name
// HTMLDivElement

document.createElement('a').constructor.name
// HTMLAnchorElement

document.createElement('foo').constructor.name
// HTMLUnknownElement
```