# Get selected element type

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get the type of element, that I've got selected using jQuery selectors.

Markup:

```
<select name="a"></select>
<input name="b" type="text" />
<textarea name="c"></textarea>
```

Javascript:

```
var field_names = new Array(
    'a',
    'b',
    'c'
);

for(var i = 0; i < field_names.length; i++) {
    var field = $('[name=' + required_fields[i] + ']:visible');

    // ?????
    // What do I write here to get one of those outputs:
    //    Element with name a is <select>
    //    Element with name b is <input>
    //    Element with name c is <textarea>

    alert('Element with name ' + required_fields[i] + ' is ' + element_type);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I determine the type of an HTML element in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254302/how-can-i-determine-the-type-of-an-html-element-in-javascript)

Answer (score 81, accepted):

Simple:

```
var element_type = '<' + field.get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() + '>';
```

In a nutshell, this retrieves the DOM element associated with `field` and gets its tag name via the `tagName` attribute inherited from `DOMElement`, then transforms the result to lowercase using `String`'s `toLowerCase()` method. Some browsers will return the `tagName` in uppercase, so for consistency you should transform it to lower case.

Comment: Just reiterating the importance of `case`! in the hope that the next person reads the answer properly!

Answer (score 95):

Use the DOM element's [`tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.tagName) property:

```
var element_type = field[0].tagName;
```

Note that browsers are not entirely consistent about the case returned by `tagName`, so you should probably call [`toLowerCase`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/ToLowerCase) to be safe: `field[0].tagName.toLowerCase()`.