# javascript: check if element can accept a value

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to do something like this (pseudo-code):

```
if ( element can accept a value )
    element.value = "my new value";
else
    element.innerHTML = "my new value";
```

So for input, textarea, etc it will set the `value`, but for div or span it will set the `innerHTML`.

Or should I simply set both `value` and `innerHTML`, since innerHTML is harmless to set for input elements?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? Why don't you know whether the element is an input or a content element?

Comment: typeof element.value  !='undefined'

Comment: I don't think there is a clean way to do that but you could try something like that :

`if (element.tagName == 'input' || element.tagName == 'testarea' || ...)`

Comment: @Barmar the program that renders the HTML will be either sending an inputarea or static text (div), depending on the user's edit permissions.  I'd rather not depend on things like checking for a class name to see if it's one of my input elements

Comment: You also could use `element.nodeName == "INPUT"` as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/254302/how-can-i-determine-the-type-of-an-html-element-in-javascript).

Comment: @Kevin or `element.nodeName == "SELECT"`, also `TEXTAREA`

Comment: @Barmar yeah I just didn't feel like typing out every tag it could be, I figure the asker can sort that out :P

Comment: @Kevin looks like element.nodeName it is ;-) thanks...and if you want to post up the answer I will gladly accept it.  Sorry for the newbie question, I did try to research this.

Comment: @Kevin I thought he was trying to avoid having to enumerate all the types, and use something more automatic.

Comment: Basic check to see if it has the property is all that is needed. No real reason to maintain a list unless you like to maintain lists of elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use

```
if (element.nodeName == "INPUT" || element.nodeName == "TEXTAREA") {}
```

The `"INPUT"` and `"TEXTAREA"` are the tags you're using, so add whichever ones you're trying to detect as you see fit.

[Here is a more in-depth explanation of `nodeName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeName).

---

As a side note, you can significantly simplify this to

```
if (element.nodeName != "DIV") {}
```

But this can only be done if you are certain that any element that gets passed in will be a type of input or a `div`.

Answer (score 1):

Basic in operator should do the trick

```js
function hasValue(elem) {
  return 'value' in elem
}

console.log('input', hasValue(document.querySelector('#t1')))
console.log('div', hasValue( document.querySelector('#t2')))
console.log('select', hasValue(document.createElement('select')))
console.log('textarea', hasValue(document.createElement('textarea')))
console.log('h1', hasValue(document.createElement('h1')))
console.log('span', hasValue(document.createElement('span')))
```

```html
<input type="text" id="t1" />
<div id="t2"></div>
```

Comment: Looks great as a very simple way to check if element is input!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [**attributes**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/attributes) property to get the tag name

```js
function updateElement(elemId) {
  var attr = document.getElementById(elemId).attributes;

  if (attr[0].ownerElement.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    document.getElementById(elemId).value = 'adding to value'
  } else {
    document.getElementById(elemId).innerHTML = 'added in inner html'
  }

}

updateElement('inputElem')
updateElement('divElem')
```

```html
<input id='inputElem'>
<div id='divElem'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `in` operator to check if *any* element has the `value` attribute - see demo below:

```js
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.body.children, function(element) {
  if ('value' in element)
    element.value = "form";
  else
    element.innerHTML = "not form";
});
```

```html
<input/>
<div></div>
<textarea></textarea>
<select>
  <option value="not form">Not form</option>
  <option value="form">Form</option>
</select>
```

If you are opting for `jQuery`, there's a simpler option the `:input` selelctor - see demo below:

```js
$('body').children().each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':input'))
    $(this).val("form");
  else
    $(this).html("not form");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input/>
<div></div>
<textarea></textarea>
<select>
  <option value="not form">Not form</option>
  <option value="form">Form</option>
</select>
```